# Remove "-" from values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel like this:

```
AD-001-L-PETG
AD-101-L
BD-03-L-PETG
```

And I want to make to look like this, :

```
AD-001 L PETG
AD-101 L
BD-03 L PETG
```

So basicly i want to remove "-" after first showingand put empty space " ".
This is what i find:

=SUBSTITUTE(A2,-,"")

But this is not work good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-"," ",2),"-"," ",2)`

Comment: Or this: =LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,4)-1) & SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,4),999),"-"," ")

Answer (score -1):

You need to add one more column where you apply in this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," ")` it will shown result is **AD 001 L PETG**. then second column you put this formula `=REPLACE(B1,FIND(" ",B1),1,"-")` i will show your ans like **AD-001 L PETG**.